# Jquery multiple accordion menu

Tags: jquery

i am create accordion menu.In that i have two filters.Ex: test 1 and test 2.Each have more then two parents like this

Menu 1

info 1
->test 1
->test2
info 2
->test1
->test2

Menu 2

info 1
->test 1
->test2
info 2
->test1
->test2

On page load,Menu 1 and menu 2 first level open by default.parent only (info1 and info 2 only in both menus).if we click info 1 of menu 1 its display child of info 1 others automatically hide.i try following code but i am not getting my expected output.here i enclosed by code .any guide me do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0073)http://blog.evaria.com/wp-content/themes/blogvaria/jquery/index-multi.php -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Accordion Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        /* A few IE bug fixes */
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        * html ul ul li a { height: 100%; }
        * html ul li a { height: 100%; }
        * html ul ul li { margin-bottom: -1px; }

        body { padding-left: 10em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        #theMenu { width: 200px; height: 350px; margin: 30px 0; padding: 0; }

        /* Some list and link styling */
        ul li { width: 200px; }
        ul ul li { border-left: 25px solid #69c; padding: 0; width: 175px; margin-bottom: 0; }
        ul ul li a { display:block; color: #000; padding: 3px 6px; font-size: small; }
        ul ul li a:hover { display:block; color: #369; background-color: #eee; padding: 3px 8px; font-size: small; }
        /* For the xtra menu */
        ul ul ul li { border-left: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; padding: 0; width: 175px; margin-bottom: 0; }
        ul ul ul li a { display:block; color: #000; padding: 3px 6px; font-size: small; }
        ul ul ul li a:hover { display:block; color: #369; background-color: #eee; padding: 3px 8px; font-size: small; }


        li { list-style-type: none; }
        h2 { margin-top: 1.5em; }

        /* Header links styling */
        h3.head a { 
        color: #333;
        display:block; 
        border-top: 1px solid #36a;
        border-right: 1px solid #36a;
        background: #ddd url(down.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position: 98% 50%;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        }
        h3.head a:hover { 
        color: #000;
        background: #ccc url(down.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position: 98% 50%;
        }
        h3.selected a { 
        background: #69c url(up.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position:98% 50%;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        }
        h3.selected a:hover { 
        background: #69c url(up.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position:98% 50%;
        color: #36a;
        }

        /* Xtra Header links styling */
        h4.head a { 
        color: #333;
        display:block; 
        border-top: 1px solid #36a;
        border-right: 1px solid #36a;
        background: #eee url(down.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position: 98% 50%;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        }
        h4.head a:hover { 
        color: #000;
        background: #ddd url(down.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position: 98% 50%;
        }
        h4.selected a { 
        background: #6c9 url(up.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position:98% 50%;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        }
        h4.selected a:hover { 
        background: #6c9 url(up.gif) no-repeat; 
        background-position:98% 50%;
        color: #36a;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function(){  
    // applying the settings
    jQuery('#theMenu').Accordion({
        active: 'h3.selected',
        header: 'h3.head',
        alwaysOpen: false,
        animated: true,
        showSpeed: 400,
        hideSpeed: 800
    });
    jQuery('#xtraMenu').Accordion({
        active: 'h4.selected',
        header: 'h4.head',
        alwaysOpen: false,
        animated: true,
        showSpeed: 400,
        hideSpeed: 800
    });
}); 
</script>
<ul id="theMenu">
    <li style="position: static; ">
        <h3 class="head selected"><a href="javascript:;">Title 1</a></h3>
            <ul style="display: block; ">
                <li><a href="#">Content 1 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 1 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 1 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    <li style="position: static; ">
        <h3 class="head selected"><a href="javascript:;">Title 2</a></h3>
            <ul style="display:block; ">
                <li>
                    <ul id="xtraMenu">
                        <li style="position: static; ">
                            <h4 class="head"><a href="javascript:;">Content xtra 2 1a</a></h4>
                                <ul style="display: none; ">
                                    <li><a href="#">Content 2 1 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Content 2 1 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Content 2 1 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li style="position: static; ">
                            <h4 class="head "><a href="javascript:;">Content xtra 2 1b</a></h4>
                                <ul style="display: none; ">
                                    <li><a href="#">Content 2 2 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Content 2 2 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Content 2 2 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 2 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 2 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3 class="head selected"><a href="javascript:;">Title 3</a></h3>
            <ul style="display:block; ">
                <li><a href="#">Content 3 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 3 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 3 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3 class="head selected"><a href="javascript:;">Title 4</a></h3>
            <ul style="display: block; ">
                <li><a href="#">Content 4 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 4 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 4 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3 class="head selected"><a href="javascript:;">Title 5</a></h3>
            <ul style="display:block; ">
                <li><a href="#">Content 5 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 5 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Content 5 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could show us a jsfiddle for this :)